# Is it possible to render Graphics with more than "Byte" bitdepth?

Tags: graphics, color, image, rendering

I wonder is it possible to render `Graphics` in *Mathematica* with bitdepth higher than `"Byte"` which is the maximum bitdepth supported by the Windows XP operating system (it is so-called "True Color")? Tracing the rasterization with the option `TraceInternal->True` shows that `Graphics` is always rendered to a matrix of `Integers` in the range from 0 to 255, then it may be converted to `Reals` if requested but such conversion does not increase the bitdepth, of course: it changes only the internal representation of the `Image`. For example, let us consider rendering of `VertexColors`:

```
Cases[Trace[
  Image[Graphics[
    Polygon[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}}, 
     VertexColors -> {Red, Green, Blue}], ImageSize -> 4], "Real"], 
  TraceInternal -> True], 
 x_List /; MatrixQ[Unevaluated@x, NumberQ], {1, Infinity}]
```

One can see matrixes of values between 0 and 255 in spite of requested `"Real"` bitdepth. Let us compare the results of rendering with different requested bitdepths:

```
In[21]:= Image[
  Graphics[Polygon[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}}, 
    VertexColors -> {Red, Green, Blue}], ImageSize -> 4], "Real"] === 
 Image[Image[
   Graphics[
    Polygon[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}}, 
     VertexColors -> {Red, Green, Blue}], ImageSize -> 4], "Byte"], 
  "Real"]

Out[21]= True
```

It is obvious that the requested bitdepth does not change the real rendering bitdepth.

So the question is: is it possible to render `Graphics` with bitdepth higher than `Byte`?

Comment: off topic: [Windows 7 is said to support 30 and 48 bit color depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_new_to_Windows_7#Other_changes).

Comment: @Silvia Thanks. It would be interesting to know the output of my test code (in the question) under Windows 7 or 8. I am working under Windows XP.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7780327/618728

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do anything in the kernel. When you rasterize a `Graphics` expression it is processed by ``System`ConvertersDump`ConvertGraphicToRasterDataPacket`` which assembles an `ExportPacket` and sends it to the front end. The front end returns a ``System`ConvertersDump`Bitmap`` expression, which contains compressed bitmap data with a bit depth of 8. The `ExportPacket` has a `ColorSpace` option but nothing for bit depth. So I think unless there is a front end option to change the rendering bit depth (I can't see one myself), I suspect the answer is no.

Comment: @Simon how did you come by this knowledge?  Experimentation?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, yes, experimentation with `Trace` and my `Spelunk` function.

Comment: @Simon Which OS you are using? This behavior may be OS-specific (although I think it is probably not). In any case, I think it is worth to post you comment as an answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. My win7 gives `True` too. I personally doubt that `Image` can handle colors "deeper" than true color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on experimentation with *Mathematica* 8.04 on Windows 7 64-bit:

I don't think it's possible to do anything in the kernel. When you rasterize a `Graphics` expression it is processed by `` System`ConvertersDump`ConvertGraphicToRasterDataPacket `` which assembles an `ExportPacket` and sends it to the front end. The front end returns a `` System`ConvertersDump`Bitmap `` expression, which contains compressed bitmap data with a bit depth of 8. The `ExportPacket` has a `ColorSpace` option but nothing for bit depth. So I think unless there is a front end option to change the rendering bit depth (I can't see one myself), I suspect the answer is no.

To investigate on your own system, you can run the `Trace` looking for calls to the front end:

```
g = Graphics[
   Polygon[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}}, 
    VertexColors -> {Red, Green, Blue}], ImageSize -> 4];

Trace[Image[g, "Real"], MathLink`CallFrontEnd, TraceInternal -> True]
```

The output on my system contains 4 front end calls, of which the last one is interesting:

[image]

You can see that the `ExportPacket` contains a `Notebook` expression within which is the box form of the original graphics. Neither the `Notebook` options or the `ExportPacket` options contain anything that looks like a bit depth.

The expression returned from the front end is a `` System`ConvertersDump`Bitmap `` object, whose first element is a string of strange characters - this is the compressed bitmap data. You can copy the `` MathLink`CallFrontEnd `` expression from the trace output and evaluate it to get at the data (copying the compressed data string directly does not seem to work)

```
result = MathLink`CallFrontEnd[ (** copied from Trace output **)]
```

The data can be decompressed using:

```
Developer`RawUncompress[result[[1, 1]]]
```

> {255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
>   255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
>   255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 234, 184, 182, 188,
>   188, 165, 178, 233, 177, 255, 255, 255, 231, 216, 222, 74, 74, 107,
>   212, 229, 218, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 183, 183, 232, 255,
>   255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
>   255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
>   255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
>   255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
>   255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
>   255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255}

It is clear that the data is 8 bit.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. In v.8.0.4 this works, but in version 9.0.0 the attempt to `Trace` ``MathLink`CallFrontEnd`` crashes the kernel.