# Colorcode mesh tiles

Tags: graphics, functions, color, mesh

I have a polygon and 3 lists of points (H, M, L) inside this polygon. I would like to create a mesh inside this polygon and to colorcode each tile of the mesh depending on how many H, M and L there are inside.

I think I can use RGB to define the color based on the number of H, M and L but I'm clueless on how to specify the mesh and to define if a point belong to a tile rather than another.

Any suggestions?
I'm adding a little example:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], White,Polygon[{{-0.5, 5.5}, {10.5, 5.5}, {-0.50,-0.50}}]}];
H = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 3}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 5}, {0.5, 2}, {0.5, 4}, {0.5, 5}, {3, 5}};
M = {{1, 1.5}, {2, 1.5}, {5, 3.5}, {4, 2.5}, {2, 4}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}, {6, 4.5}, {6, 4}, {8, 5}};
L = {{4, 3.5}, {0.5, 1}, {2, 3}, {5, 4}, {4, 5}, {7, 5}, {7, 4}, {6, 3.5}, {8, 4.5}, {9, 5}};
```

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the code for the polygon and the points so one can visualize what you have in mind.

Comment: Unfortunately they derive from experiments so they may change (Irregular polygon defined just by segments). I'm trying to be as general as possible, I can in case provide one test with a simple triangle and few points.

Comment: Please post the triangle and the points.

Comment: Thanks so much for your kindness, just added some points and their representation.

Comment: "Mesh" is a bit vague here. Do you want a regular grid, a triangulation... which one?

Comment: Ya, you are right, is just that since I do not know a priori what kind of  shape will have the polygon I just used mesh. Probably  a triangular grid will be more appropriate in covering odd corners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**A related thread about coloring a mesh.**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134625/boundary-cells-of-a-mesh)

---

How I understand the question:

1. to make *some*, e.g. triangular, mesh of the region;
2. count the number of points from the three categories in each of the mesh cells;
3. define a color based on the counts;
4. color the cell with that color.

I decided to use the relative counts to define an `RGBColor` (see also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129624/22013)).

---

```
mesh = TriangulateMesh[#, MaxCellMeasure -> 10] & @
  BoundaryMeshRegion[{{-0.5, 5.5}, {10.5, 5.5}, {-0.50, -0.50}}, 
   Line[{1, 2, 3, 1}]]
```

[image]

(For arbitrary points `pts` forming the vertices of the polygon: `BoundaryMeshRegion[pts, Line[Range@Length@pts~Join~{1}]]`; one might want to play with `MaxCellMeasure` too.)

The cells are extracted with

```
cells = MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2]
cells // Short
```

> {Polygon[{{-0.5,5.5},{1.25,2.5},{3.,5.5}}],<<4>>,Polygon[<<1>>]}

The indices of the faces:

```
ind = MeshCellIndex[mesh, 2]
```

> {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}}

Then the counts, colors and styling:

```
counts = Table[ (Count[RegionMember[cells[[i]], #] & /@ #, True]/Length[#]) & /@ 
           {H, M, L}, {i, 1, Length @ cells}];

color = RGBColor /@ counts

style = Style @@@ (Transpose@{ind, color})
```

And coloring the `mesh`:

```
HighlightMesh[mesh, {style}]
```

[image]

---

To place the relative `H-M-L` counts on `mesh`:

```
lab = Transpose @ {ind, Text /@ counts};
HighlightMesh[mesh, Labeled[#1, #2] & @@@ lab]
```

[image]

On the colored mesh:

```
HighlightMesh[mesh, {style, Labeled[#1, #2] & @@@ lab}]
```

[image]

although it's not very readable; one might consider white text and some non-white background.

Comment: I used RGB based on the question, but for readability it might be better to assign a color to each class (Red, Blue, Green) and use the most abundant group to define the lightness of the color that is ascribed to it; sth like `Darker[Red, 3/10]`; maybe some rescaling is needed also.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. It's very clear and helpful