# Pixelized 2d projection of 3d list

Tags: plotting

I would like to visualize some 3d data. What I want is similar to

```
ListPlot3D[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}, 
 Mesh -> All]
```

[image: what I dont want]

however, the result should look like

[image: what I do want]

which is an array plot:

```
ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {10, 20}]]
```

The crucial difference is, that I would prefer to be able to plot my Data straight away (where z should be colormapped, i.e. 0: black, 1:white).

```
{{x1, y1, z1}, ... , {xn, yn, zn}}, x_{n+1} - x_{n} != y_{n+1} - y_{n}
```

It's generated via c++. ideally, i would like to read it out of a HDFS dataspace. Finally, it looks something like this:

```
{{0.0, 0.0, 0.12343},{0.0,0.1,0.5233},{0.0,0.2,0.86493},{0.0,0.4,0.9854},...},
{0.4, 0.0, 0.45347},{0.4,0.1,0.7231},{0.4,0.2,0.9433},{0.4,0.4,0.7459},...},
{0.8, 0.0, 0.3455},{0.8,0.1,0.3457},{0.8,0.2,0.5422},{0.8,0.4,0.01208},...},
...
{1.2, 0.0, 0.35425},{1.2,0.1,0.68425},{1.2,0.2,0.6546},{1.2,0.4,0.8243},...}}
```

Of course, I could transform it to

```
{{a11, a12, ..., a1n}, ... , {am1, am2, ..., amn}}
```

via

```
z = data[[All, 3]];
Partition[z, 4];
```

manually (thanks Okkes), but then, I loose the information of pixel size

```
(x_{n+1} - x_{n}) x (y_{n+1} - y_{n})
```

This means, the pixels may be supposed to look non-quadratic.

I have spent some time to find a solution, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you need the 3D surface with discrete "pixels" like set of squares at the different altitudes? Just use the `InterpolationOrder->0` inside your `ListPlot3D` if so.

Comment: thanks, but not really... should really be png-ish in the end. The thing is, that dx may not be equal to dy, otherwise @Okkes answer would work fine

Comment: Can you post small portion of your data? How do you generate your data?

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Thanks for taking the [tour]. Be sure you have learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include minimal working example of your code and data in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: thanks @rhermans, I dont quite understand, what Im doing wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Strongly related QA from where I'm borrowing the technique](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134600/26956)**

Caveat: the ordering of the mesh cells is not the same as the ordering of the initial data points. Using some help from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109687/26956) I fix this with an undocumented function `` Region`Mesh`MeshMemberCellIndex ``.

Let's generate some test data:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {36, 3}];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[data[[;; , ;; 2]]];
ind = MeshCellIndex[mesh, 2];
ordereddata = 
 data[[Region`Mesh`MeshMemberCellIndex[mesh][
   data[[;; , ;; 2]]][[;; ,2]] // Ordering]]
style = Style @@@ (Transpose@{ind, GrayLevel /@ ordereddata[[;; , 3]]});
HighlightMesh[mesh, {style}]
```

> [image: matrixplot]

This method also works for a rectangular grid:

```
data = Table[{i, j, RandomReal[]}, {i, 0, 5, .4}, {j, 0, 2, .2}] // Flatten[#, 1] &;
```

> [image: rectangular]

and it is quite easy to clip the large boundaries like so:

```
With[{xstep = data[[;; , 1]] // Union // Differences // Min,
  ystep = data[[;; , 2]] // Union // Differences // Min},
 xrange = (data[[;; , 1]] // MinMax) + {-.5, .5} xstep;
 yrange = (data[[;; , 2]] // MinMax) + {-.5, .5} ystep;]
mesh = VoronoiMesh[data[[;; , ;; 2]], {xrange, yrange}];
```

> [image: better]

Take care though, the last code snippet has no error checking, so may clip a bit more than desired on an unstructured grid.

Comment: thanks a lot, this works

Answer (score 0):

Assume your data is in `data={{x1, y1, z1}, ... , {xn, yn, zn}}` form and you only care about plotting `z`values, then you can do the following. It is up to you how you partition your data.

```
      SeedRandom@2
data = RandomReal[1, {36, 3}];
z = data[[All, 3]];
Row[{ArrayPlot[Partition[z, 4]], ArrayPlot[Partition[z, 6]], 
  ArrayPlot[Partition[z, 9]]}, Spacer@20]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, this kind of does, what it is supposed to, however, I forgot to mention, that dx may not be equal to dy

Comment: What do you mean by that?